# Laravel 5.5 "UnexpectedValueException" on Mac, installation error

Tags: php, macos, laravel, composer-php, file-permissions

I am a web developer. Previously I used to code in Windows, I'm new to Mac.
I used Laravel previously many times on Windows, never had this problem.
I checked the File Permission on Mac very carefully, both **Read/Write** permissions are enabled for all along with **Enclosed Items**.

I Googled it, no luck. CodeIgniter and WordPress are working very well.

Is it possible to fix? I carefully installed Lavael with Composer, the same file are smoothly working on Windows.

I'm using **XAMPP**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to change permissions

- Open terminal.
- sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/storage
- sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/bootstrap

But for me I prefer to use Vagrant/Homestead, everything is set and ready to go, check this out [Homestead/Vagrant](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)

Comment: I always needed to mount the folder from XAMPP to access it. From terminal, the otp/lampp/htdocs doesn't exist.

Comment: That's why I recommend homestead/vagrant.

Comment: Thanks for telling a new way. I later found an easy solution, using MAMP instead of XAMPP. Problem fixed smoothly.